# ¿Cómo evitar que el css filter y rgba apliquen cambios al texto o otros elementos hijos?

Tags: html5, css3

> Esta pregunta es basada desde una pregunta ya respondida por [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29189/c%C3%B3mo-aplicar-una-capa-oscura-transparente-a-una-imagen-de-fondo) pero con un nuevo problema.

Consto con dos ejemplos muy útil.

En este ejemplo se crea una capa semitransparente encima de la imagen, utilizando los elementos `::before` o `::after`.

```css
#image {
  background-image:url(http://www.gelfuzion.com/img/slides/nivo/bg-1.jpg);
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

#image::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  }
  
.detalle {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="detalle">
      <h2>TITLE TITLE</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque harum a, cum natus fugit quidem, odio ea. Error ad a placeat omnis tempora nisi rerum, minima earum, sed dolor?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El segundo ejemplo se utiliza los filtros CSS para cambiar el contraste/luminosidad de la imagen.

```css
#image {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  background-image:url(http://www.gelfuzion.com/img/slides/nivo/bg-1.jpg);
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  filter:brightness(0.4);
}
  
.detalle {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="detalle">
      <h2>TITLE TITLE</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque harum a, cum natus fugit quidem, odio ea. Error ad a placeat omnis tempora nisi rerum, minima earum, sed dolor?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora el problema esta que el efecto aplica cambios al texto, el color blanco del texto pasa a ser un color gris.

Cómo aplicar los efectos del ejemplo solo a la imagen de fondo.

Comment: El filtro se aplica a todo el elemento, lo cual implica que también se va a aplicar a sus hijos por eso aparece tu texto en gris. Si quieres que el efecto sólo se aplique a la imagen lo ideal sería que tuvieras un div a la misma altura de `container` que muestre la imagen de fondo y a ese div le apliques el filtro, de esa manera el filtro se aplica a la imagen y lo que está dentro de detalle no se ve afectado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno no vi la necesidad de utilizar el after o before , Prueba este código:

```css
#image {
  background-image:url(http://www.gelfuzion.com/img/slides/nivo/bg-1.jpg);
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position:relative;  
  

}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
   
.detalle {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="detalle">
      <h2>TITLE TITLE</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque harum a, cum natus fugit quidem, odio ea. Error ad a placeat omnis tempora nisi rerum, minima earum, sed dolor?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para el segundo ejemplo seria:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  
}

#image {
  background-image:url(http://www.gelfuzion.com/img/slides/nivo/bg-1.jpg);
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;   
  filter:brightness(0.4);
}
   
.detalle {
  position: absolute;  
  color:#fff;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image">
  </div>

   <div class="detalle">
     <h2>TITLE TITLE</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque harum a, cum natus fugit quidem, odio ea. Error ad a placeat omnis tempora nisi rerum, minima earum, sed dolor?</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfecto, y en el asunto del filtro `filter` que solución se podría aplicar?

Comment: @J.Doe listo ya actualize la respuesta